# PS1R not aligning correctly

Tags: bash, prompt

I am writing a script to construct my bash prompt but the right side prompt is printing an extra character (one that belongs at the beginning of the left side of the prompt) at the very end of the right hand side. What is the solution to this please and thanks for any input;here is the code:

````
        !/bin/bash

        function LeftRightNewlinePrompt {

        local SAVE='\x1b[s'
        local RESTORE='\x1b[u'

        <<COLORS
        export BLACKBG='00;00;00'
        export WHITEFG='ff;ff;ff' # in decimal=255;255;255
        export GRAYBG='41;4a;4c' # in decimal=65;74;76
        export LIGHTGRAYBG='c0;c5;ce' # in decimal=192;197;206
        export BLUEBG='00;5b;96' # in decimal=00;91;150
        export ORANGEFG='ff;a7;00' # in decimal=255;167;00
        export ORANGEBG='ff;a7;00' # in decimal=255;167;00
        export GREENBG='36;80;2d' # in decimal=54;128;45
        COLORS

        # set your RGB colors
        pipe_color='255;255;255'
        pipe_bg_color='65;74;76'
        username_color='0;0;0'
        username_bg_color='192;197;206'
        at_color='255;255;255'
        at_bg_color='65;74;76'
        host_color='255;255;255'
        host_bg_color='00;91;150'
        workingdir_color='255;255;255'
        workingdir_bg_color='54;128;45'
        date_color='00;00;00'
        date_bg_color='255;167;00'
        time_color='255;167;00'
        time_bg_color='00;00;00'
        bar_spaces_bg_color='167;173;186'

        # leave this block alone
        pipe_color_set="\x1b[38;2;${pipe_color}m"
        pipe_bg_color_set="\x1b[48;2;${pipe_bg_color}m"
        username_color_set="\x1b[38;2;${username_color}m"
        username_bg_color_set="\x1b[48;2;${username_bg_color}m"
        at_color_set="\x1b[38;2;${at_color}m"
        at_bg_color_set="\x1b[48;2;${at_bg_color}m"
        host_color_set="\x1b[38;2;${host_color}m"
        host_bg_color_set="\x1b[48;2;${host_bg_color}m"
        workingdir_color_set="\x1b[38;2;${workingdir_color}m"
        workingdir_bg_color_set="\x1b[48;2;${workingdir_bg_color}m"
        date_color_set="\x1b[38;2;${date_color}m"
        date_bg_color_set="\x1b[48;2;${date_bg_color}m"
        time_color_set="\x1b[38;2;${time_color}m"
        time_bg_color_set="\x1b[48;2;${time_bg_color}m"
        color_reset_set='\x1b[0m'
        bar_spaces_bg_color_set="\x1b[48;2;${bar_spaces_bg_color}m"

        # leave this block alone
        pipe=$(printf "${pipe_color_set}")
        pipebg=$(printf "${pipe_bg_color_set}")
        username=$(printf "${username_color_set}")
        usernamebg=$(printf "${username_bg_color_set}")
        at=$(printf "${at_color_set}")
        atbg=$(printf "${at_bg_color_set}")
        host=$(printf "${host_color_set}")
        hostbg=$(printf "${host_bg_color_set}")
        workingdir=$(printf "${workingdir_color_set}")
        workingdirbg=$(printf "${workingdir_bg_color_set}")
        date=$(printf "${date_color_set}")
        datebg=$(printf "${date_bg_color_set}")
        time=$(printf "${time_color_set}")
        timebg=$(printf "${time_bg_color_set}")
        colorreset=$(printf "${color_reset_set}")
        bar_spaces_bg_color=$(printf "${bar_spaces_bg_color_set}")

        export PS1RHSa=$(printf "%([ %F ])T")
        export PS1RHSb=$(printf "%([ %H:%M ])T")

        export PS1RHSa_stripped=$(sed "s,\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]),,g"         <<<"$PS1RHSa") 
        export PS1RHSb_stripped=$(sed "s,\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]),,g" <<<"$PS1RHSb")

        export sizeofPS1RHSa=${#PS1RHSa_stripped}
        export sizeofPS1RHSb=${#PS1RHSb_stripped}
        export sizeofPS1RHS=$((sizeofPS1RHSa + sizeofPS1RHSb))

        export PS1='\[${SAVE}\e[${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}C\e[${sizeofPS1RHS}D\[${date}${datebg}\]${PS1RHSa}\[${time}${timebg}\]${PS1RHSb}${RESTORE}\[${pipe}${pipebg}\]|\[${username}${usernamebg}\][ \u ]\[${pipe}${pipebg}\]|\[${at}${atbg}\]@\[${pipe}${pipebg}\]|\[${host}${hostbg}\][ \h ]\[${pipe}${pipebg}\]|\[${colorreset}\]'

        }

        LeftRightNewlinePrompt
```[![these prompts should be on same line][1]][1]


ok here's what it looks like right now..


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlIky.jpg
````

Comment: those spaces before <<<"$PS1RHSa") and <<<"$PS1RHSb") are not there in my original file just so you know..

Comment: I'll have a closer look, but my first reaction is that _none_ of these variables need to be exported.

Comment: Please add what your current prompt looks like and what it _should_ look like

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you might be missing some `\[` and/or `\]`.

Try this, setting PS1 in pieces for, hopefully, better readability

```bsh
PS1=''

# first line
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s\e[%dC\e[%dD\]' "$SAVE" "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" "$sizeofPS1RHS")
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s%s\]%s'  "$date" "$datebg" "$PS1RHSa")
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s%s\]%s'  "$time" "$timebg" "$PS1RHSb")
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s\]' "$RESTORE")

# second line
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s%s\]|'       "$pipe"     "$pipebg")
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s%s\][ \u ]'  "$username" "$usernamebg")
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s%s\]|'       "$pipe"     "$pipebg")
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s%s\]@'       "$at"       "$atbg")
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s%s\]|'       "$pipe"     "$pipebg")
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s%s\][ \h ]'  "$host"     "$hostbg")
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s%s\]|'       "$pipe"     "$pipebg")
PS1+=$(printf '\[%s\]' "$colorreset")
```

---

I have a similar prompt. This is what it looks like

```
˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙ bash 5.1 ˙˙ 12:48:03
glennj@raspberrypi:~/src/other/bash (master (clean))
+$
```

- I use multiple shells regularly, with similar prompts, so I put the name and version of the shell in the prompt to remind me where I am.
- the `+` is the mode indicator for readline vi-mode. This does not play well with a multi-line prompt

I have this

```bsh
__bash_prompt() {
    local last_status=$1
    local cwd user_host_path
    # shellcheck disable=SC2001
    cwd=$( sed "s,^$HOME,~," <<<"$PWD" )
    # shellcheck disable=SC2154
    user_host_path="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot) }$(id -un)@$(hostname -s):$cwd"

    # terminal title
    if (( BASH_VERSINFO[0] > 3 )); then
        echo -ne "\e]0;$user_host_path\a"
    fi

    # prompt is printed to stderr
    {
        # separator and date
        local spaces time dot='˙' dots
        printf -v spaces "%*s" $(($(tput cols) - 22)) ""
        dots=${spaces// /$dot}
        if (( BASH_VERSINFO[0] <= 3 )); then
            time=$(date '+%T')
        else
            printf -v time '%(%T)T' -1
        fi
        printf "%s bash %s ${dot}${dot} %s\n" "$dots" "${BASH_VERSION:0:3}" "$time"

        # exit status of last command
        if ((last_status != 0)); then
            local color_bold='\e[0;1m'
            local color_reset='\e[0m'
            printf "${color_bold}[%d]$color_reset " "$last_status"
        fi

        # user@host, directory, git branch
        local git_status; git_status=$(git_current_branch -s)
        printf '%s\n' "${user_host_path}${git_status:+" ($git_status)"}"
    } >&2
}

# ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039713/different-bash-prompt-for-different-vi-editing-mode
# a single-line PS1 allows the show-mode-in-prompt inputrc setting to be useful
PROMPT_COMMAND='__bash_prompt $?'
PS1='\$ '
```

So I make PROMPT_COMMAND do all the hard work, and PS1 just puts the cherry on top.

Comment: ok I will try some of these and get back to you guys..

Answer (score 0):

ok after a bunch of tries I got what I wanted (I'm sure some of you out there could come up with a more elegant version :))so in case anyone was trying to do the same, here is mine:

```
#!/bin/bash

function setColors {
local SAVE=$'\[\e[s\]'
local RESTORE=$'\[\e[u\]'
pipe_color=$'\001\e[38;2;255;255;255m\002'
pipe_bg_color=$'\001\e[48;2;65;74;76m\002'
username_color=$'\001\e[38;2;0;0;0m\002'
username_bg_color=$'\001\e[48;2;192;197;206m\002'
at_color=$'\001\e[38;2;255;255;255m\002'
at_bg_color=$'\001\e[48;2;65;74;76m\002'
host_color=$'\001\e[38;2;255;255;255m\002'
host_bg_color=$'\001\e[48;2;00;91;150m\002'
workingdir_color=$'\001\e[38;2;255;255;255m\002'
workingdir_bg_color=$'\001\e[48;2;54;128;45m\002'
date_color=$'\001\e[38;2;0;0;0m\002'
date_bg_color=$'\001\e[48;2;255;167;0m\002'
time_color=$'\001\e[38;2;255;167;0m\002'
time_bg_color=$'\001\e[48;2;0;0;0m\002'
bar_spaces_color=$'\001\e[48;2;167;173;186m\002'
bar_spaces_bg_color=$'\001\e[48;2;167;173;186m\002'
reset_color=$'\001\e[00m\002'
}

setColors

function printBar {
seq -s ' ' 0 $(($COLUMNS-53)) | tr -d '[:digit:]'
printf '${reset_color}'
}


function setPS1 {
shopt -s checkwinsize; (:;:)
resize &>/dev/null
# DATE=$(date +'[%F]')
# TIME=$(date +'[%H:%M:%S]')
PS1R='${pipe_color}${pipe_bg_color}|${date_color}${date_bg_color}$(date +"[%F]")${reset_color}${pipe_color}${pipe_bg_color}|${time_color}${time_bg_color}$(date +"[%H:%M:%S]")${pipe_color}${pipe_bg_color}|${reset_color}'
PS1='${pipe_color}${pipe_bg_color}|${username_color}${username_bg_color}[\u]${pipe_color}${pipe_bg_color}|${at_color}${at_bg_color}@${pipe_color}${pipe_bg_color}|${host_color}${host_bg_color}[\h]${pipe_color}${pipe_bg_color}|${reset_color}'
printf -v PS1 "\033[s%*s\033[u%s%s%s%s" $((COLUMNS+187)) "${PS1R}" "${PS1}" "${bar_spaces_color}${bar_spaces_bg_color}$(printBar)"
}
 
PROMPT_COMMAND=setPS1
```